# Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 stalled

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

I've been trying to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 using the update manager. Everything went fine at first, and I haven't gotten any errors, but the progress has been stopped at "Preparing to configure debconf" for about 24 hours now. Is there anything I should do about this or a way to stop the upgrade?

Comment: Do you have "> Details" link in the update window? Try clicking on it - you'll see console output there, it may be asking you some question there, something like "config file changed, do you want to override?"

Comment: Well, it's not your fault, it shouldn't have happened... Normally it supposed to display a normal GUI dialog, but sometimes it thinks it is running in the console so it falls back to text interface. I'll re-post my comment as an answer in case you want to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I swear I have seen this question before... I just don't recall where...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have "> Details" link in the update window? Try clicking on it - you'll see console output there, it may be asking you some question there, something like "config file changed, do you want to override?"

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't take 24 hours.  Your upgrade has likely failed.  I had a similar problem and wound up.

1. Boot from CD
2. Copy my /home/xxx to a external HDD.
3. Do a fresh install of 12.04
4. Copy my /home/xxx from external HDD to the hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  In my "Distribution Upgrade   -- Upgrading Ubuntu to version 12.04" window I had a >terminal.  I opened that and I had to say OK to something about stopping services.  (I didn't know it was going to work, so I didn't write it down for later reference, so I cannot quote exactly what it was.)  Anyway, after I OKed it, the install continued.