# Upgrading Ubuntu to 12.04 stuck

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 stalled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129803/upgrade-from-11-10-to-12-04-stalled)

While upgrading from 11.10 to 12.04, I'm stalled at the step:

Installing new version of config file `/etc/init/udevtrigger.conf`

The Terminal in the Distribution Upgrade window is expanded, there is no prompt for user input. I've hit enter a few times but it doesn't change anything but add a blank line after the last print statement. It's been sitting for ~6 hours at this stage.

No other windows or dialog boxes are open. The upgrade has progressed through "Preparing to Upgrade", "Setting new software channels", and "Getting new packages". Under the progress bar (which estimates 1 day 2 hours remaining, and has for some time), it says `Preparing to configure libpcap0.8`. I'd take a screen-shot, but it won't let me save the file anywhere. The progress bar is about 1/3 complete.

Comment: I find it's always better to do a fresh install rather than to try upgrades.IMHO

Comment: @blueXrider - I can appreciate that, but it's not particularly helpful at this point in the game.

Comment: @blueXrider - I already expanded the terminal window and I'm not being prompted for any input. I already went through a portion of the upgrade that did that (where I got stuck for a while until I noticed that's what was going on, yes), but at this point, that's not the problem. Thanks for looking around, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a last resort, boot into Ubuntu using a live cd copy whatever files you need and also your package list and perform a fresh install. Using your package list you can reinstall programs pretty easily.